# Django change textfield

Tags: django, django-forms

Currently am using this textfield for my model

```
#model
class NoLoginPsuedoAppointment(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)


#form
class NoLoginPsuedoAppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comments = forms.Textarea()

    class Meta:
        model = NoLoginPsuedoAppointment
        fields = [
            "comments",
        ]
```

Which comes out looking like this

[image]

Is there a way to change where the textarea begins so that comments is on top of the textarea or on its top left instead of being on its bottom left? Can this be changed through the django forms? or do I need to change it through css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure you can change it. that's only the form field `label` you can put it anywhere you want. I guess you rendered the form as `{{ form.as_p }}` or as `table` or ... so you have to loop through the form fields

```
<form ... >
  {% csrf_token %} <!-- if thats POST -->
  {% for field in form %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">{{ field.label }}</div>
      <div class="col-8">
        {{ field }}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

in above example I just created a row and putted the `label` and `field` in the same row, you can put it as you wish. and also you can access the **field errors** with `{{ field.errors }}`.